# HttpUrlConnection to authenticate user, android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been working in the user's authentication for a long time but every time I run my app this error appears:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
      Process: com.g11.colinaapp, PID: 9752
      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
       Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
ProcessRecord{26a3953 9752:com.g11.colinaapp/u0a72} (pid=9752,
uid=10072) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
      at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
      at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
      at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
      at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:56)
      at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
      at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
      at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is my code. And I know that I have to change `HttpClient` to `HttpUrlConnection` but I don't know how and I've been searching for a long time, too.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

```
package com.g11.colinaapp;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.auth.AUTH;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
            "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
    };
    private static final String AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://colinaapp.com/api/v1/authenticate/";
    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
   private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmail;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;
    public static String userToken = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
//        

        final EditText etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        final EditText etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        final TextView tvLog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        final TextView tvOlvide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOlvide);


        //recuperar contraseña
        tvOlvide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent olvidoIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Olvide.class);
                Login.this.startActivity(olvidoIntent);
            }
        });

        // Set up the login form.
        mEmail = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    //attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        TextView mUsernameSignInButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
       mUsernameSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);


    }

    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }


    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    public void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mEmail.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String username = mEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            mEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmail;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isUsernameValid(username)) {
            mEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmail;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(username, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((String) null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isUsernameValid(String username) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return username.length() > 1;
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    public void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addUsernamesToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }


    private void addUsernamesToAutoComplete(List<String> emailCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(Login.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailCollection);

        mEmail.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<NameValuePair>> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<NameValuePair> doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            try {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mEmail));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ColinaApp", "Login: " + e.getClass());
                Log.d("ColinaApp", "Login: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            String text = "";

            // Send data
            try {
                // Send POST data request
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(AUTH_ENDPOINT);

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    StatusLine sl = response.getStatusLine();
                    int statusCode = sl.getStatusCode();

                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        HttpEntity hp = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream content = hp.getContent();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            builder.append(line);
                        }

                        String responseBody = builder.toString();
                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                        userToken = jObject.getString("token");

                        Log.d("ColinaApp", "Login: auth successful");
                        return nameValuePairs;
                    } else {
                        Log.d("ColinaApp", "LoginActivity: error: " + statusCode + " : " + sl.getReasonPhrase());
                        System.out.println(text);
                        return null;
                    }

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ColinaApp", "Login: " + e.getClass());
                Log.d("ColinaApp", "Login: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d("ColinaApp", "Login Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                Log.d("ColinaApp", "Login Exception: " + ex.getClass());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("ColinaApp", "Login: Response: " + text);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final List<NameValuePair> success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success != null) {
                //show the user list
                Intent m2 = new Intent(Login.this, Inicio.class);
                m2.putExtra("userToken", userToken);
                startActivity(m2);
            } else {
                Log.d("ColinaApp", "Auth FAILED");
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }



    public static class Global {
        public static String Token = userToken;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put permission in the Manifest and authorize it cause it's a dangerous permission (adapt this code to your case) :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
                //This is called if user has denied the permission before
                //In this case I am just asking the permission again
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("" + permission + " is already granted.");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already put the permissions:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

Comment: I think that is the compatibility with the rest of the code. Because in this I have HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpPost, etc. and in the other activities I have HttpUrlConnection.

Just this code run perfectly but with the other technology of codes doesn't.